# How to call nest factory in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have requirement below. I have one factory. I have added code snippet below.

```
myapp.factory('sadadpaymentapi', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction', 'leaselisting', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction, leaselisting) {
    var sadadpaymentapiobject = {};
    var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
    var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
    var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
    var urlapi = baseurl + "api/ServiceRequest/CreateRSSedad/";
    sadadpaymentapiobject.callsadad = function (PaymentType) {
        leaselisting.leaselisting().then(function (response) {
        //Problem in calling
        }, function (error) { });
        var request = {
            url: urlapi,
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                SRActivityID: LoginID,
                PaymentType: PaymentType,
                PaymentAmount: "100"
            },
            headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
        };
        return $http(request);
    }
    return sadadpaymentapiobject;
}]);
```

Here is my second factory leaselisting

```
myapp.factory('leaselisting', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction', function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction) {
    var leaselistingobject = {};
    var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
    var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
    var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
    leaselistingobject.leaselisting=function(){
    var requestObj = {
        url: "api/ServiceRequest/GetROLSPSRLeaseList/",
        data: {
            LoginID: LoginID,
            RSAccountNumber: $cookieStore.get("AccountNumber")
        },
        headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
    };
    $http(requestObj).then(function (response) {
    }, function (error) {
    });
    }
    return leaselistingobject;
}]);
```

I have found error in below line

```
 leaselisting.leaselisting().then(function (response) { //Problem in calling
        }, function (error) { });
```

May i am i doing anything wrong in the above code? May i know is it possible to call one factory from another? The response i get from leaselisting i want to pass it in  callsadad function of sadadpaymentapi. So can someone hep me in the above code? I am getting error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in the `leaselisting.leaselisting().then(function (response) {},function(error){});`

Also is there any way I can directly inject factory like payment amount: inject factory something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that `leaselistingobject.getValue` is an asynchronous function.
So first of get your value :

```
leaselistingobject.getValue = function(){
   var requestObj = {
       url: "api/ServiceRequest/getValue/"
   };
   return $http(requestObj).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

And then use it. To let all async actions finish we use angulars `$q`.[Here](https://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/) you can find a small tutorial.

```
myapp.factory('sadadpaymentapi', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 'cfg', 'ScrollFunction', 'leaselisting', '$q',function ($http, $cookieStore, cfg, ScrollFunction, leaselisting, $q) {
var sadadpaymentapiobject = {};
var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
var urlapi = baseurl + "api/ServiceRequest/CreateRSSedad/";
sadadpaymentapiobject.callsadad = function (PaymentType) {
    var leastListingPromise = leaselisting.leaselisting();
    var getValuePromise = leaselisting.getValue();
$q.all([leastListingPromise, getValuePromise]).then(function (responses) { 
    //Here you have both responses in an array
    var request = {
        url: urlapi,
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            SRActivityID: LoginID,
            PaymentType: PaymentType,
            PaymentAmount: responses[1]
        },
        headers: ScrollFunction.getheaders()
    };
    return $http(request);


    });   
}
return sadadpaymentapiobject;
}]);
```

To make `leaselisting()` return the response of the request change the end of the function from

```
$http(requestObj).then(function (response) {
}, function (error) {
});
```

to

```
return $http(requestObj).then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
}, function (error) {
});
```

If wont do anything about possible errors you can omit the error function part:

```
return $http(requestObj).then(function (response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it possible to do something payment amount:inject factory and assign values. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: In sadadpaymentapi factory I have callsadad method. In that method I have three input params such as sractivituid,paymenttype and payment amount. Now I want to assign values to payment amount from the leaselisting factory so can I do something payment amount:get value from lease listing API.

Comment: So you expect e.g leaselistingobject.getValue to return a number which you want to assign to PaymentAmount in sadadpaymentapiobject.callsadad ? Please work on your naming. It's quite confusing

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to implement. I am getting provider lease listing must return a value from $get factory method. How can I fix this?

Comment: Also I am getting error in lease listing.leaselisting! I did not understand this line. Thanks